# How can I configure not allowing submission of form without filling in the values?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I have developed a form, wherein under a section, a user presses the '+' button to add a row, and then fill in the values. The code is below.

```
<uib-accordion>
    <uib-accordion-group heading="Parameters" is-open="true">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Key Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="cftParams in ctrl.app.cftParams track by $index">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName"
                           ng-model="cftParams.key" placeholder="Enter name of parameter" ng-minlength='3'
                           ng-maxlength='100' required>
                    <span ng-show="!cftParams.key.length">Please enter a key.</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" name="inputValue"
                           ng-model="cftParams.value" placeholder="Enter value" ng-minlength='3'
                           ng-maxlength='100' required>
                    <span ng-show="!cftParams.value.length">Please enter a value.</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="cbtn cbtn-plus" ng-click="ctrl.app.cftParams.splice($index, 1)">-
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button class="cbtn cbtn-plus" ng-click="ctrl.AddParameter()">+</button>
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

Now, I want, if the user presses the '+' button, he/she will have to enter some values for 'key' and 'value'. That is he cannot submit the form without entering the values for key and value (if he has pressed the + button). If he doesn't wish to enter those values, he should delete the row by pressing the '-' button. How can I configure this? I tried adding <\span> but that does something else.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have **`<form>`** in the page which ends after the **`<button>`** then you can disable the form button by this

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="formname.$invalid" class="cbtn cbtn-plus" ng-click="ctrl.AddParameter()">+</button>
```